# validate url without www. or http://

Tags: jquery, regex, validation, url, preg-match

I'm looking to validate an URL. I have already a script that validates to not allow `www.` and `http://` but i need to also validate for `.co.uk` `.com` etc.

My script won't run if they enter something like `example.co.ukff`.

I have this for a full URL:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+$/i
```

I just need to validate the end `.co.uk` or `.com` etc.

Answer (score 4):

Try This...

`/^http:\/\/|(www\.)?[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/`

It's working exactly what you want.

it takes with or with out `http://, https://,` and `www`.

Comment: Did you try it? It matches `http://` alone and `[a-z]{2,5}` is really poor to match TLDs, see: https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 2):

Far from pretending this to be the ideal regex to match urls, the particular problem of only matching urls which do *not* begin with *www* can be resolved with a **[negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead)** : `(?!www\.)`
meaning that the following text should not be *www.*

Therefore, your regex adapted with this negative lookahead:

`^(?!www\.)[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.+[A-Za-z0-9.\/%&=\?_:;-]+$`

matches the following urls

```
google.com
google.com/
goggle.com/q
google.com/q?q=1&h=en
google.co.uk
google.co.uk/
goggle.co.uk/q
google.co.uk/q?q=1&h=en
w.google.com
w.google.com/
w.goggle.com/q
w.google.com/q?q=1&h=en
209.85.149.105
209.85.149.105/
209.85.149.105/q
209.85.149.105/q?q=1&h=en
209.85.149.105:80
209.85.149.105:80/
209.85.149.105:80/q
209.85.149.105:80/q?q=1&h=en
example.domain.bogus.number.of.subdomains/index.htm
```

but not those:

```
www.google.com
www.google.com/
www.google.co.uk
www.google.co.uk/
www.google.co.uk/q
www.google.co.uk/q?q=1&h=en
http://209.85.149.105/
http://209.85.149.105:80/
http://www.google.com
https://www.google.com
http://google.com
https://google.com
```