# jquery validation for field with default value

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/

I am using above plugin for jquery validation of registration form

it is working properly, but in my form there is one field name "domain" whose default value has been set to "www." so user have to just write other part domain.

so practically it is not blank any time, so it is not validating if user left that filed with default value, here is my jquery and html code

```
    <script>
$().ready(function() {

        $("#frm").validate({
            rules: {
                domain: "required",
                uname: "required",
                password:'required',
                cpassword:'required',
                fname:'required',
                lname:'required',
                bussname:'required',
                city:'required',
                state:'required',
                pincode:'required',
                country:'required',
                phone1:'required',
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                code:'required',


            },
            messages: {
                domain: "Please enter domain name",
                uname: "Please enter user name",
                password: "Please enter password",
                cpassword:'Please confirm password',
                fname:'Please enter first name',
                lname:'Please enter last name',
                bussname:'Please enter practice',
                city:'Please enter city',
                state:'Please enter state',
                pincode:'Please enter zip code',
                country:'Please select country',
                phone1:'Please enter phone',
                email: 'Please enter email address',
                code: 'Please enter security code',


            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

My html Form

```
    <form name="frm" id="frm" action="ezregistration2.php" method="post">


<input name="domain" type="text" id="domain"  value="www."  size="40" class="tb7"   />



<input name="uname" type="text" id="uname" value="" size="40" class="tb7" onkeyup="countchars(this);" />


<input name="password" type="password" id="password"  size="40" class="tb7">

<input name="cpassword" type="password" id="cpassword"  size="40" class="tb7">


<input name="fname" type="text" id="fname" value="" size="40" class="tb7" >


<input name="lname" type="text" id="lname" value="" size="40" class="tb7" >


<input name="bussname" type="text" id="bussname" value="" size="40" class="tb7">


<input name="address1" type="text" id="address1" value="" size="40" class="tb7">




<input name="address2" type="text" id="address2" value="" size="40" class="tb7">


<input name="city" type="text" id="city" value="" size="40" class="tb7" >
                                                    <input name="state" type="text" id="state" value="" size="40" class="tb7" >


<input name="pincode" type="text" id="pincode" value="" size="40" class="tb7" >

<select name="country" id="country" class="tb7" style="width:225px;"> 
<option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option></select>

<input type="text" name="phone1" size="40" id="phone1" value="" onkeypress="return noNumbers(event)" class="tb7">

<input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" size="40" class="tb7">

<input type="text" name="code" id="code" size="8" class="tb7" style="width:100px" />

<input name="Submit" type="image" src="homeimages/submit.jpg" class="submitbtn" style="outline:none;" />


<input type="hidden" name="sub" value="1">
</form>
```

is there anyway that it should not allow default value too upon validation ?

Comment: Please refer this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4691070/validate-url-without-www-or-http

Comment: look for custom validation : `jQuery.validator.addMethod("domain", function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^http:\/\/mycorporatedomain.com/.test(value);
}, "Please specify the correct domain for your documents");`

Comment: it cant be done on existing code ?

Comment: Don't pre-fill the `value`.  That's what the `placeholder` attribute is for.  There is also a rule called `url` that can be used to validate a URL.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/url-method/

Comment: And finally, there is a way to keep the `value` attribute but you must create a custom method.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/2733922/594235

Answer (score 0):

Add before `$("#frm").validate({`

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("domain", function(value, element){ return this.optional(element) || value != "www."; }, "Please enter domain name");
```

And in your rules change `domain: "required",` to

```
domain: {
    required: true,
    domain: true
},
```